# Simplifying PDE by change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How does one use the substitution $\hat{x}=e^{-r(T-t)}x$ to get from,

$$
\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma(x, t)^2x^2\frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial x^2}+rx\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial x} = 0
$$

to

$$
\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma}(\hat{x}, t)^2\hat{x}^2\frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}^2} = 0
$$

where $\hat{\sigma}(\hat{x}, t)=\sigma(x, t)$.

My steps are as follows,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial x} &= \frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}}\frac{\partial \hat{x} }{\partial x} =\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}}e^{-r(T-t)}\\
\frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial x^2} &=\frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2 \hat{x} }{\partial x^2}\right)^2+\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}}\frac{\partial^2 \hat{x} }{\partial x^2}\\
&=\frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}^2}e^{-2r(T-t)}+0
\end{align}
$$

Subsituting back into the PDE I get,

$$
\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma}(\hat{x}, t)^2 \frac{\hat{x}^2}{e^{-2r(T-t)}} \frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}^2}e^{-2r(T-t)} + r\frac{\hat{x}}{e^{-r(T-t)}}\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}} e^{-r(T-t)}= 0\\
\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\hat{\sigma}(\hat{x}, t)^2 \hat{x}^2 \frac{\partial^2 \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}^2} + r\hat{x}\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}}= 0\\
$$

I don't see how the $r\hat{x}\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat{x}}$ term would disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps are correct concerning the change of $\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial x}$ but not the change of $\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t}$ where a term $\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat x}r\hat x$ is missing :

$\hat F(x,t)$ becomes $\hat F\left(e^{r(T-t)}\hat x,t\right)$ and one have to take account of $\frac{\partial e^{r(T-t)\hat x} }{\partial t}=-e^{r(T-t)\hat x}r\hat x$

So, $\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t}$ is replaced by $\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial x}e^{r(T-t)\hat x}r\hat x= \frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial t}-\frac{\partial \hat{F} }{\partial \hat x}r\hat x$

Comment: ah i see... i need to apply multivariable chain rule. thanks!